# mappedBy refers to the Class Name or to the Table Name?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-many

When we use the mappedBy annotation in @OneToMany for example, did we mention the Class Name or the Table Name ?

An exemple :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_tab")
public class Customer {
   @Id @GeneratedValue public Integer getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
   private Integer id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer_tab")
   @OrderColumn(name="orders_index")
   public List<Order> getOrders() { return orders; }

}
```

So which of these two is correct ? :

- @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer_tab")
- @OneToMany(mappedBy="Customer") ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Neither is correct.  From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy()):

> mappedBy
>   public abstract java.lang.String mappedBy
>   The field that owns the relationship. Required unless the relationship is unidirectional.

The `mappedBy` annotation indicates that the field which it labels is owned by the other side of the relationship, in your example the other side of a one-to-many relationship.  I don't know exactly what your schema is, but the following class definitions would make sense:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_tab")
public class Customer {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="customer")
    @OrderColumn(name="orders_index")
    public List<Order> getOrders() { return orders; }

}

@Entity
public class Order {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "customerId")
    // the name of this field should match the name specified
    // in your mappedBy annotation in the Customer class
    private Customer customer;
}
```

Comment: Ah ! this is why i'm getting annotation error!! Thanks